# Where to Set Column Width in NSTableView After Updates

Tags: notifications, nstableview, column-width

I managed to write a function to set the column width by max string length. I need this to prevent long strings from clipping, wrapping etc.
My problem is now, where do I put the function. In other words when do I know when the tableview finished loading or updating? I cant find any available notifications for `NSTableView`.

here is my func:

```
func columnWidthByMaxStringLength(forColumn: Int) -> CGFloat {

    let table = equationTableView!
    var width = 0
    for i in 0...table.numberOfRows-1 {
        let view = table.view(atColumn: forColumn, row: i, makeIfNecessary: true)
        let size = view?.fittingSize
        width = max(width, Int((size?.width)!))
    }

    return CGFloat(width)
}
```

I tried to call this function within the `NSTableView` delegate `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?` but it is not the right place. It throws an error.

Comment: Do you use Cocoa bindings?

Comment: @Willeke, no, I do the whole table view setup within the view controller (datasource and delegate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of the column can be calculated when the table view and the data are loaded, before updating the table view. You can reuse the cell view.

For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.data = …
    self.sizeToFit(column: tableView.column(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("name")))
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func sizeToFit(column: Int) {
    if let view = self.tableView.view(atColumn: column, row: 0, makeIfNecessary: true) as? NSTableCellView {
        let key = self.tableView.tableColumns[column].identifier.rawValue
        var width = self.tableView.tableColumns[column].minWidth
        for object in self.data {
            view.textField?.objectValue = object[key]
            let size = view.fittingSize
            width = max(width, size.width)
        }
        self.tableView.tableColumns[column].width = width
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Willeke, thanks for the response but is this approach not only working once the viewcontroller is starting? How about updating the tableview when its content will change?

Comment: Are the cells mutable?

Comment: I'm not sure how to be sure but I guess the cells are mutable.

Comment: How does the content change, does the user edit the text field?

Comment: Yes, she does. But not directly within the table cell. The content is as input from another text field but the string length (column width) will depend on the users input.

Comment: Update the width of the column after you update the data before you update the table view.

Comment: Mhm, still struggling. The column width will adapt but not for the last column. The width is calculated correctly but the last column is not expanded to that value.

Comment: OK, got it now. In IB for the tableview is a parameter `Column Sizing` which was set to "last Column" I changed it to "none" and its working now. Thanks!